# Is LibreOffice Writer able to read properly Ms Office Word docx Files?

Tags: libreoffice

Is LibreOffice Writer able to read properly Ms Office Word docx Files?

I think it can't and users should be aware of it!

I tried to open many documents .docx created with Ms Office 2007 and appeared modified/transformed when I tried to open them with LibreOffice.

Can I do anything about it?

Comment: ... it depends on the version of libreoffice ... support is better in the latest version.

Comment: If you don't need to edit the .docx files, why don't you convert them to PDF? - This way almost everything stays formatted as it is. For me this was till now the only solution...

Comment: Abiword should read and write .docx

Comment: Read yes ! write no. In libre office 3 there is still lack of support for SmartArts,Shapes and Charts.

Answer (score 14):

Yes it can... Most of the time without issues.

LibreOffice supports by default several formats including the ones used by Microsoft Office, including the Office Open XML specification from `.docx`, `.pptx` and `.xlsx`.

That does not mean that everything will look exactly the same when you open a file in MS Office 2007 and in LibreOffice. To tell the truth not all files created in MS Office 2007 will open the same even in Ms Office 2010, and the opposite is also true.

You should be aware that Office XML specifications were created by Microsoft and that nuances can be seen using different versions of the editor that you are using. That will also be true even with Microsoft software.

Just don't expect that everything will be the same all the time. Things like missing fonts and weird formatting in the original document will cause massive issues while trying to open it in LibreOffice. Open XML formats are bad. End of story.

As an option [you can however run MS Office in Ubuntu](http://appdb.winehq.org/appview.php?iVersionId=4992) easily. Nothing is impossible. Just buy a MS Office license, run the installer with Wine and you can do all the things you do in Windows using MS Office 2007 under Ubuntu.

Comment: The important thing nobody mentioned: if one have a problem with «docx» compatibility between Libre Office and MS Office, since «docx» now is an open standard, it is pretty much possible that [this is the guilty of MS Office](https://brattahlid.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/is-docx-really-an-open-standard/), which *(what an irony)* doesn't work with «docx» properly. So, if anybody have problems with the MS Office, feel free to recommend them to upgrade to software that does following standards, like LibreOffice, for example.

Comment: @Bruno, one thing I didn't get. You say, that OpenXML is bad, but still suggesting to run MS Office on Linux? Open XML, as far as I know, was developed by Microsoft but is not in use anymore.. am I wrong? generally, which is more consistent, clean and comprehensive, MS Office or LibreOffice?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well (it doesn't help that MS keeps changing their formats) :(

**Hot Tip**

One solution I found that seemed to work is to ask people I am working on documents with to simply save it in an older doc version. It seems to guarantee that I could see the document in the original format **and** the people I was collaborating with were able to properly open my documents properly (previously saving LibreOffice in docx was preventing them from doing that).

Hope that helps some folks :)

** Update: It appears as though the latest release of Open Office has better DocX support (only available in the [latest version of Ubuntu 12](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/libreoffice-360-beta-1-released-ubuntu.html) though)

Comment: Hey no problem... also I just updated this to note that there is better support (apparently) in Ubuntu 12's LibreOffice latest release. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another factor that often is overlooked when compatibility is discussed is that documents created in MS Office in Windows often uses MS fonts that is not available in Linux. An exchanged font makes documents look different and the layout will get lost. 
This can partly be fixed by using exactly the same fonts in MS Office and LibreOffice.

Comment: It's not only the fonts its the format of the document a friend of mine gave me to print a docx document and its format, objects,frames etc were misplaced completely altering the document in a big way, this was very embarassing.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, I cant use with any Documents that my business creates in Office 2007/10 - the formatting is all over the place.

Really should not be touted as a "full office suite compatible with MS office - it really isn't and in no way should it be used for businesses.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it has some basic compatibility but as people have said here, the ususal workflow where a Windows/Office user sends you a docx which you edit and send back is fundamentally unfeasible with LibreOffice, and the main reason I still need to boot into Windows. Any file with tables or advanced formatting will tend to break.

I can't yet verify if the new/beta version does handle these better but at the moment I would still consider it risky

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, LibreOffice still has poor formatting compatibility with MS Office, despite a few improvements in the latest version. It's still way short for being able to open a Word document, edit it, save it, then open it in Word  without losing formatting in one way or another. Docx compatibility is even worse than doc.

The only office suite for Linux that provides true interoperability with Microsoft Office is SoftMaker Office. Its word processor TextMaker opens and saves doc and docx without any flaws. Amazing. A free 30 day trial version of SoftMaker Office is available on SoftMaker's website for you to prove it.

Comment: [FreeOffice TextMaker](http://www.freeoffice.com/en/features-freeoffice-textmaker) unfortunately [does NOT save as .DOCX](http://imgur.com/RIPGoZ2). The newest Word format it supports is Word 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a new beta update with DOCX improvements.
[A List of Changes](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/3.6) is available.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```