# Libreoffice and Microsoft office

Tags: libreoffice, microsoft-office

Is there a way to make libreoffice compatible with Microsoft office? Do I just need it to be in the same file format? Or will it still mess up each other?

Comment: Recent versions of MS Office can actually open `.odt` files, which is what LibreOffice uses by default.

Comment: Please put this in the answers.

Comment: The basic functions are similar but formatting and complex functions do not always cross over.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/117602/is-libreoffice-writer-able-to-read-properly-ms-office-word-docx-files and the nice Bruno Pereira's answer there. or my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/630849/how-can-i-manage-to-read-my-microsoft-office-documents-in-libre-office-without-a

Comment: @UbuntuUser - It's a bit short for an answer, and also it doesn't directly answer the question. So it's better suited as a comment.

Comment: Libreoffice Writer is also usually able to open `.doc` and `.docx` without any problems.

Comment: Do you mean the interface? Or file management?

Comment: Both... I mean will it be completely compatible at least on the libreoffice side.

Comment: I would expect "challenges" opening Word documents like a 200 page Users Guide or Excel VBA  Spreadsheets that tracked bar-coded customer orders through a warehouse picking / auditing / shipping phases. But for smaller documents you should have no problems other than font substitutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For basic documents, saving LibreOffice documents as Microsoft Word 2007-2013 XML is just fine.  If you are collaborating with others on a document and formatting matters, particularly if you have embedded images, track changes, comments, et al, then I recommend agreeing with your collaborators on using either LibreOffice or Microsoft Word. There are too many small things that get lost in translation that can be a huge time suck.  As an Ubuntu user, I pitch LibreOffice for collaboration but have MS Word 2010 installed under Wine as a fall-back.  Wine support for MS Office 2010 is excellent, rock solid.